# Getting the number of users online on a specific post

Tags: laravel, websocket, pusher, laravel-echo

I have some blog with some posts. Every page has a block "Read now" which contains post titles with count of readers at that moment (guests and auth users).The question is how to get these counters.
I am usinng laravel Echo with beyondcode/laravel-websockets.
Tryed to using presence channel, but it requires authorization.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method [by SaeedPrez](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/find-out-all-logged-in-users?page=0#reply=318054).

Alternatively, you could try going through Laravels `Request` like this:

```
Request::session()->all()
```

Try dumping and dying (`dd()` function) and see how you could parse the given response. As an idea maybe use a CRON and save the variables in cache.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can try init Echo.listen() on public channel once user hit the post page. From that, you can build logic to see how many people are in that post.id page by temporarily store the count data somewhere in Redis or just in database the belong to that specific post. And remove the count when user leave the page by calling the Echo.leave().

There's no true solution yet since presence channel require authenticated user.